# Integral Measures: Identification

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

**Problem**

Given a Borel space $\Omega$.

Consider a Borel measure:
$$\mu:\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}:\quad\mu\geq0$$

Regard a Borel measure:
$$\rho\geq0:\quad\mu_\rho(A):=\int_A\rho\,\mathrm{d}\mu$$

Denote its Borel support:
$$\sigma_\rho:=\left({\bigcup}_{U\in\mathcal{T}(\Omega):\mu_{\rho}(U)=0}U\right)^\complement$$

> Then isometrically:
>   $$\mathcal{L}(\sigma_\rho;\mu_\rho)\cong\mathcal{L}(\sigma_\rho;\mu)$$

How can I prove this?

**Attempt**

Define the map:
$$U_\rho:\mathcal{L}(\sigma_\rho;\mu_\rho)\to\mathcal{L}(\sigma_\rho;\mu):\eta\mapsto\eta\rho$$

It is isometric since:
$$\|U_\rho\eta\|=\int|\omega|\rho\mathrm{d}\mu=\int|\omega|\mathrm{d}\mu_\rho=\|\eta\|$$

So also well-defined:
$$\|\omega\|=0\implies\|U_\rho\omega\|=0$$

But why surjective?

Comment: What is $\mathcal{T}(\Omega)$?

Comment: @NateEldredge: The topology on the Borel space.

Comment: @triple_sec: Thanks for having a look over it!!!

Comment: "Borel space" to me means just a set with a $\sigma$-algebra satisfying certain properties; it doesn't have a topology.  Maybe you want to say "Polish space"?

Comment: Hint: given $f$, it should be pretty clear what $\eta$ has to be in order to ensure $U_\rho \eta = f$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I mean the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology. Mostly, this goes under the name Borel $\sigma$-algebra - but not always.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Intuitively yes: It must be formally given by $V_\rho\vartheta:=\vartheta\rho^{-1}$. But the formal inverse may be far from making sense at all. For example if the induced measure acts effectively only on $[0,1]$ but one considers the whole real line $\mathbb{R}$. Then it is certainly not surjective i.e. the inverse doesn't exist. Thus the Borel support must play an essential role.

Comment: $f \rho^{-1}$ makes sense at every $x$ for which $\rho(x) \ne 0$.  Show that this is the case for almost every $x \in \sigma_\rho$.  For $x \in \sigma_\rho$ for which $\rho(x) = 0$, and for every $x \notin \sigma_\rho$, you can define $\eta(x)$ to be whatever you want...

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes that is the point I'm having problem with, i.e. $\rho>0\bmod\mu$.

Comment: Also, can I offer a suggestion?  As you study this subject, you might want to also improve your writing style.  Three words and an equation is rather tedious and tends to omit context.  If you look at books and papers, they are not written this way.  Use complete sentences, including equations only where needed.  You also have a tendency to introduce notation (usually nonstandard) without explaining it - this doesn't help either.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Sure. Thanks for the suggestion!! I will think about it.

Comment: @NateEldredge: The assertion is actually wrong! *(See answer.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The assertion is wrong:*

Given the interval $[-1,1]$.

Consider the Borel measure:
$$\mu:\mathcal{B}([-1,1])\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}:\quad\mu:=\lambda+\delta$$

Regard the Borel measure:
$$\rho:=1-1_{\{0\}}:\quad\mu_\rho(A):=\int_{[-1,1]}\rho\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\lambda$$

It has Borel support:
$$\sigma_\rho=\sigma(\lambda)=[-1,1]$$

But it is not surjective:
$$\vartheta:=1_{\{0\}}:\quad\vartheta\notin\mathcal{R}U_\rho$$

Concluding counterexample.